# React select onChange empty event

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following React component which uses a `select` tag which state is being managed by the component:

```
<main id='homescreen-container'>
                {/* TODO: Add maxLength after deciding on a font size */}
                <textarea readOnly id="recorded-text-view" value={this.state.displayedContent}></textarea>
                <button className="button" onClick={this.toggleRecording}>{!this.state.recording ? "Înregistrează" : "Stop"}</button>
                <h5>Paragraful curent</h5>
                    <select id="current-paragraph" value={this.state.workingPage.WorkingParagraphIndex} onChange={(event) => this.changeCurrentParagraph(event)}>
                        {this.state.workingPage.Paragraph.map((val, index) => (
                            <option key={index} value={index + 1}>{index + 1}</option>
                        ))}
                    </select>
                <button className="button" onClick={this.createNewParagraph}>Adaugă un paragraf</button>
                <button className="button" onClick={this.deleteCurrentParagraph}>Șterge paragraful curent</button>
                <button className="button" onClick={this.saveFile}>Salvează</button>
            </main>
```

My problem is that when I am trying to handle the `onChange` event, the event passed to the handler has `null` for the target property. Here is my handler:

```
changeCurrentParagraph = (event: any) => {
        console.log(event);
        this.setState((prev: HomescreenState) => ({
            workingPage: prev.workingPage.changeWorkingParagraph(event.target.value)
        }))
    }
```

This isn't working, throwing the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`. Any idea what could be the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you set `this.state.workingPage.WorkingParagraphIndex` in constructor? or does it have any initial value?

Comment: Yes it has an intial value,but I don't see why that would be a problem since the error thrown is related to the event object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is likely arising from the way you are trying to set the value inside of setState. Try changing your code to follow this pattern:

```
changeCurrentParagraph = (event: any) => {
        console.log(event);
        const myVal = this.state.workingPage.changeWorkingParagraph(event.target.value) //assuming you are returning a value from this
        this.setState((prev: HomescreenState) => ({
            workingPage: myVal
        }))
    }
```